# What can make a web application to not recognize the very inputting of values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

Often, in different websites, when I input text into a field with JavaScript (for the sake of automating form filling):

```
document.querySelector("#username").value = "USERNAME";
```

I encounter the following problem.

### My problem

The above *very inputting* of text via JavaScript, either manually by `devtool console` or by a `userscript manager`, isn't effective so the form could not be submitted and I am asked something like "fill in data in all fields".

A way to deal with that is to delete the last (or first) character of the inputted text and then re-input that character manually myself and then the ext will be recognized but it's not really a solution.

### A failed solution

I have tried to cope with the aforementioned problem with the following pattern, which failed:

**1)** Manually mouselick on all fields and then execute in devtool console:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("keydown"));
dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));
dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

> true

**2)** Manually mouselick on all fields again;

### My question

What can make a web application not recognizing the very inputting of values with JavaScript?
What can prevent the data being recognized unless at least one characters of it is manually changed?

Comment: Events aren't triggered when you change an input value from JavaScript, only when it's changed by the user.

Comment: It means that there is *some* event that is fired by default which isn't happening when you try to insert the data programmatically. You can try for other events: `keypress`, `input`, etc. *Hopefully* the site's JS doesn't check if the event is trusted before continuing, else you're out of luck

Comment: @CertainPerformance are you sure that there would be case that I am out of luck wit this? Several programmers much more experienced in JS than I am always told me something like "in JS there is nothing you cannot do to imitate a user if you are sophisticated enough".

Comment: You might want to write an answer based on what you and Barmar wrote and I replied to you.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. There are almost always workarounds, but if the site's script is large and minified, it may take way too much effort to figure out what it's doing and how to bypass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities of how a page may not recognize a programmatically inputted value are:

It may be listening for a different event from the one you're triggering. There are *many* types of events related to inputting text, including `keypress`, `input`, and `focus`. Take a look at what's logged in the following snippet when you *manually* click on the input and press keys:

```js
let obj = input;
while (obj) {
  for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
    if (!prop.startsWith('on')) continue;
    input.addEventListener(prop.slice(2), () => console.log(prop.slice(2)));
  }
  obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

The script may require one of those initial events to be fired before it starts processing other events. For example, perhaps the script requires a `focus` event before it starts observing key changes in the input. (Similarly, the script may be listening for events in a particular order, though that'd be pretty odd)

The script may also check if the event is *trusted* or not. Only user-initiated events are trusted; events dispatched via Javascript are not:

```js
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.isTrusted);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

In a situation like the above, your options to bypass it include

- Triggering the event using something *outside* a browser, such as with AutoHotKey
- Intercepting the `<script>` that adds the functionality and tweaking it so that it doesn't check if the event is trusted. [Here's an example](https://stackapps.com/a/8532) of doing that on Stack Exchange.